# Broken Column Mapping for One to One Multi Column Foreign Key

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I have two entities `RoomNight` and `BookingCorporateDetails` in which `BookingCorporateDetails` refers to RoomNight on two columns (`booking_id` and `room_night_booking_id`).

BookingCorporateDetails is optional but RoomNight is mandatory. I am trying to create a Foreign key join on the BookingCorporateDetails table as -

**AbstractJpaEntity.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class AbstractJpaEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected Long id;

  @Column(name = "created_at")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  protected Date createdAt;

  @Column(name = "created_by", length = 32, nullable = true)
  protected String createdBy;

  @Column(name = "updated_at")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  protected Date updatedAt;

  @Column(name = "updated_by", length = 32, nullable = true)
  protected String updatedBy;

  @Column(name = "is_published", columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 1")
  protected boolean isPublished;

  @Column(name = "is_deleted", columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 0")
  protected boolean isDeleted;

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

**AbstractBookingEntity.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractBookingEntity extends AbstractJpaEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6980195228404112444L;

  @Column(name = "booking_id", nullable = false)
  protected String bookingId;

  @Column(name = "room_night_booking_id", nullable = false)
  protected String roomNightBookingId;

  public String getBookingId() {
    return bookingId;
  }

  public void setBookingId(String bookingId) {
    this.bookingId = bookingId;
  }

  public String getRoomNightBookingId() {
    return roomNightBookingId;
  }

  public void setRoomNightBookingId(String roomNightBookingId) {
    this.roomNightBookingId = roomNightBookingId;
  }
}
```

**BookingCorporateDetailsEntity.java**

```
@Entity(name = "booking_corporate_details")
@Table(name = "booking_corporate_details", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name = "key_bcd_order_sub_order", columnNames = { "booking_id", "room_night_booking_id" }) })
public class BookingCorporateDetailsEntity extends AbstractBookingEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5577224607005257364L;

  @Column(name = "btc_company")
  private String billToCompany;

  @Column(name = "cr_company_name", nullable = false)
  private String companyName;

  @Column(name = "cr_manager_name")
  private String managerName;

  @Column(name = "cr_manager_email")
  private String managerEmail;

  @Column(name = "cr_manager_phone")
  private String managerPhone;

  @OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumns({ 
    @JoinColumn(name = "booking_id", referencedColumnName = "booking_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_night_booking_id", referencedColumnName = "room_night_booking_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) 
  })
  private RoomNightEntity roomNightEntity;

  public RoomNightEntity getRoomNightEntity() {
    return roomNightEntity;
  }

  public void setRoomNightEntity(RoomNightEntity roomNightEntity) {
    this.roomNightEntity = roomNightEntity;
  }

  // Getters And Setters
}
```

**RoomNightEntity.java**

```
@Entity(name = "room_night")
@Table(name = "room_night", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name = "key_rm_order_sub_order", columnNames = { "booking_id", "room_night_booking_id" }) })
public class RoomNightEntity extends AbstractBookingEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7661960864475909694L;

  @Column(name = "ota_booking_id", nullable = false)
  private String otaBookingId;

  @Column(name = "property_id", nullable = false)
  private Long propertyId;

  @Column(name = "room_type_id", nullable = false)
  private Integer roomTypeId;

  @Column(name = "booking_status", nullable = false)
  private Integer bookingStatus;

  @Column(name = "occupancy", nullable = false)
  private Integer occupancy;

  @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
  private Long userId;

  @Column(name = "payment_mode", nullable = false)
  private String paymentMode;

  @Column(name = "stay_date")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date stayDate;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "roomNightEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private BookingCorporateDetailsEntity bookingCorporateDetailsEntity;

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

When I execute the code, I get the following exception -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:201)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:255)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:111)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:148)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookingEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [hibernateJPAConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:42)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:173)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:197)
... 17 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:340)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 30 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: bookingCorporateDetailsEntity.roomNightEntity of: com.casa.fabbookingbase.entity.RoomNightEntity
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:165)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initIdentifierPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:253)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:219)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initOrdinaryPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2218)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2265)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postConstruct(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3814)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:437)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:344)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
... 35 more
```

**PS: I have already seen multiple examples here but not able to resolve the problem even after trying those solutions.**

Comment: where are the @Id columns? are those two also primary keys of tables?

Comment: I removed that to shorten the question. My AbstractBookingEntity extends AbstractJpaEntity which has this @Id column. Let me just add that code as well.

Comment: The complete setup is working if I put Join on only one column `room_night_booking_id` but not with multi column join.

Comment: It's because both your classes have Id with an unique field in it. So they can't join for 2 fields. So you either join them for the only id they have either use a composite key

Answer (score 0):

I have done some tests and the only way that it works with two join columns is by removing the `mappedBy` from the `RoomNightEntity` entity.

You end up with sort of bi-directional mapping without the parent-child relationship:
**BookingCorporateDetailsEntity**

```
@OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({
          @JoinColumn(name = "booking_id", referencedColumnName = "booking_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "room_night_booking_id", referencedColumnName = "room_night_booking_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
private RoomNightEntity roomNightEntity;
```

**RoomNightEntity**

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "booking_id", referencedColumnName = "booking_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "room_night_booking_id", referencedColumnName = "room_night_booking_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
private BookingCorporateDetailsEntity bookingCorporateDetailsEntity;
```

Comment: I don't want it to be a bi-directional mapping. So in simple words, it is not possible with the presence of ID field in both tables. Right?

Comment: If you want it to be unidirectional then just remove @onetoone mapping from the Room night entity and just keep it on the booking entity. You original code where you used mappedBy was actually a bidirectional mapping.

Comment: I tried the Bi-Direction join as you explained but I got the Foreign Key Constraint while saving RoomNightEntity -  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:124 - could not execute statement [n/a]
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`booking_microservice`.`booking_corporate_details`, CONSTRAINT `FKmjasnoswcalcuwyqe2s6m43i7` FOREIGN KEY (`booking_id`, `room_night_booking_id`) REFERENCES `room_night` (`booking_id`, `room_ni)`

Comment: And the unidirectional? That's what you are aiming for anyway?

Comment: In the uni-direction way where BookingCorporateDetailsEntity is treated as a column, I get the exception -org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:124 - could not execute statement [n/a]
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'bookingCorporateDetailsEntity' at row 1